# get id of currently uploaded video using youtube api v3

Tags: php, youtube-api

we are creating a website where we use youtube api v3 to upload video to a youtube channel  the problem is i want the youtube id of the currently uploaded video so that i can use the id for further use..
can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get it from the 'status' of the upload.

Here's the sample:

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php#L113

Comment: well can you elaborate at which part of the code i am getting the video id????????

Comment: Line number is in the link.

Answer (score 1):

Just insert the following after uploading the file

`$htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";
$htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
$status['snippet']['title'],
$status['id']);
$htmlBody .= '</ul>';`

and do not forget to set setDefer to false

```
$client->setDefer(false);
```

Comment: Or simply add the following 
$video_key=$status['id'] ; 
echo $video_key ;